# Functional variation problem in Classical Field Theory (Non Relativistic)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

An exercise of my Homework sheet make a statement about rotational variation on a scalar field $\phi(x)$:\

*"Consider a scalar field $\phi(x,t)$ in a lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\phi, \partial_t \phi, \nabla \phi$). Consider a spatial rotation such that $x^i \longrightarrow  x'i = x^i + \omega ^i\  _j x^j = x^i + \delta x^i,$ with $ \omega ^i\  _j = - \omega ^j\  _i$. By definition, the scalar field satisfies*

$$ \phi '(x') = \phi (x) \\
\Longrightarrow\phi'(x ) = \phi (x+\delta x) \approx \phi(x)  + \partial_i \phi(x) \delta x^i\\ $$

I'm pretty sure that the last statement is wrong, I think the corrrect one should be $\phi'(x) = \phi(x - \delta x) \approx \phi(x) - \partial_i \phi(x) \delta x ^i$

The problem continues in the one item of this exercise:

"*Shot that under a spatial rotation of coordinates we have:*

$$ \delta [\partial_i \phi(x)]=  \partial' _i \phi '(x) - \partial_i \phi(x) = \partial _i \partial _j [\phi(x) \delta x^j] - \omega^j \ _i \partial_j \phi(x)" $$

Again, I'm pretty sure that this equation is wrong, because I'm only get the correct result is $\partial _i \partial _j [\phi(x) \delta x^j] + \omega^j \ _i \partial_j \phi(x)$. Can someone tell me who is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you just replace $x'$ in $\phi'(x')$ by $(x^i + \delta x^i)$ then the book or exercise is correct. Your minus sign would work replacing $x$ in $\phi(x)$ with $x= x' - \delta x.$

Comment: But since $\phi'(x') = \phi' (x+ \delta x)  = \phi(x)$, we have $\phi'(x + \delta x - \delta x ) = \phi' (x) = \phi(x - \delta x )$. Is something incorrect in this attempt?

Comment: not necessarily, note that $\delta x$ has not sign per se, one just needs to be consistent.